# Links between Test Results and Workitems in TFS2015

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015

We use TFS2015.3. We are trying to generate a report[SSRS] to list the Test Results linked to a Workitem. We checked in these Tables to get the linked items: FactWorkItemTestResult, DimTestResult, DimTestResultAttributes, FactTestResult, DimTestRun in the Warehouse DB. But we could not find the linked workitem. Can you please help us to get a way to fetch the Test Results linked to a workitem?

Regards,

Chirag D S

Answer (score 1):

You may missed the **DimWorkItem** table. Please refer to [Work Item Test Result tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/work-item-test-result-tables) for details.

> You can query for data about work items that are linked to test
>   results by using **FactWorkItemTestResult** and the associated
>   dimension tables.
>
> **FactWorkItemTestResult** is associated with the following dimension tables:
>
> - DimTeamProject
> - DimTestResult
> - ***DimWorkItem***

Besides, you can also fetch the test results whick linked to a workitem via REST API （[Get a test result](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#get-a-test-result)）:

e.g.:

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/Collection/0418Scrum/_apis/test/Runs/132/Results/100000?detailsToInclude=WorkItems
```

Comment: @Chirag Have you resolved the issue with above answer? any update?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT The link *Get a test result* is not pointing to anything related to Test Results. Do you know where to find the information now? Thanks